# Modifying CISCO openh264 to take image frames and out compressed frames

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, compression, h.264, x264

Has anyone tried to modify the CISCO openh264 library to take JPEG images as input and compress them into P and I frames (output as frames, NOT video) and similarly to modify decoder to take compressed P and I frames and generate uncompressed-frames ?

I have a camera looking at a static scene and taking pictures (1280x720p) every 30 second. The scene is almost static. Currenlty I am using JPEG compression to compress each frame individually and it is resulting in an image size of ~270KB. This compressed frame is transferred via internet to a storage server. Since there is very little motion in the scene, the 'I' frame size will be very small (I think it should be ~20-50KB). So it will be very cost effective to transmit I frames over internet instead of JPEG images.

Can anyone guide me to some project or about how to proceed with this task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing exactly what a codec does. It takes images, and compresses them. There relationship in time is irrelevant to the compression step. The decoder than decides how to display or just write them to disk. You don't need to modify open264, what you want to do is exactly what it is designed to do.

Comment: I get your point but I am asking that the openh264 API is configured to take **video container** as input (or image frames in special case) to generate a **video output**, in all cases. I want to input **frames** and get **frames** as output. **I donot have video** I just have a set of frames.